# How to trigger PHP logic on submit with an a-tag [PHP]

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, submit, form-submit

How to `form submit` with an `a`-tag i an way that the `PHP $_POST` logic is going to be triggered.

---

**Form-Structure**

```
<form id="idMonthList" method="post">
  <div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" aria-label="Toolbar with button groups">
    <div class="btn-group mr-2" role="group" aria-label="First group">
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="Januar" data-month="Januar" onclick="document.getElementById("idMonthList").submit()" href="google.com/?month=1">Januar</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="Februar" data-month="Februar" onclick="document.getElementById("idMonthList").submit()" href="google.com/?month=2" >Februar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

**What i tried**

- Submitting it via `onclick="document.getElementById("idMonthList").submit()" event`
- Submitting via `jQuery`

  ```
  $(".btn-outline-dark").click(function(oEvent) {
    const sMonth = oEvent.currentTarget.attributes["data-month"].value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {
            name: "Januar"
        },
        success: function (response) {},
        error: function (error) {}
    });
  })
  ```

---

**Issue**

The following `PHP-Code` is not going to be executed:

```
if (isset($_POST['Januar'])) {
    echo "Hallo Welt";
}
```

The only time is executed is when the form does have the following `button/s` (with `jQuery`-operation disabled):

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="Januar" data-month="Januar">Januar</button>
```

---

**Context**

I do have an [Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvuXR.png) application. The `calendar` is generated via `PHP`, i want by clicking the month to update the in `calendar` showcased `month`. When submitting (with `buttons`), the page auto-refreshes, and the `isset($_POST)`, is automatically executed, i wanted via the addition of the extra `URL` parameters to prevent this execution, as well as highlight the appropriate `button`

Comment: Firstly you're not disabling the default action of the hyperlink so it'll just redirect you to google, and probably the AJAX is never run. You need to add `oEvent.preventDefault()` in the jquery "click" listener function. Secondly why have you got `onclick` _and_ a jquery "click" event listener. Just the latter would be sufficient (especially if you want to use AJAX and not actually post the form normally). Thirdly, `success: function (response) {}` is empty so unless you are checking the Network tool in your browser to see what PHP does, you'll never know if the PHP code is executed or not.

Comment: Or to avoid the hyperlink navigation problem you could use a `<button type="button"` instead of an `<a` tag. if you want it to still _look_ like a hyperlink you could use CSS to style the button, but IMO that would just confuse your users about what the button would actually do when clicked.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ADyson, i do have another link for the `a`-tag this is why it was chosen instead of the `button`. `jQuery` was listed as an alternative to the before not that it was executed together. What should be in `success: function (response) {}` entered, in order for the `PHP` Code mentioned to be executed ?

Comment: Nothing. If you run the AJAX request, and it connects to the server, then the PHP code will be executed. But if you want to see the _output_ of the PHP code in your page, without needing to use the Developer Tools in your browser to look at it, then you'll need to write some JS code in that function. AJAX requests don't automatically update your page (because they are intended to be asynchronous background requests).

Comment: `i do have another link for the a-tag this is why it was chosen`...it's not clear what you mean. _Either_ you want to submit the form, _or_ you want to navigate to another link. Make up your mind what the link/button should do. Trying to get it to do both at once doesn't really make sense. If you need to navigate to the other link _after_ submitting the form to your PHP code, then that's something you could potentially do in the "success" function of your AJAX request, so that you know it won't happen until the AJAX request has successfully completed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your response, so what shall be introduced into jQuery success response in order for the page to be updated ? Before it was so, that jQuery submittion of the form, didnt lead to PHP code being executed which made me a bit skeptical. I did before that, submitting with buttons via jQuery and as described it didnt work. Only way it worked i.e. PHP Code executed if the jQuery is disabled and the submit buttons do have the `name` property

Comment: Introduce whatever logic you want. I don't know what bit of the page you want to update, or what you want to show on it

Comment: Just as a very basic test you could simply put `alert(response);` in there, to quickly show what PHP returned.

Comment: So now your button should be `<a class="btn btn-outline-dark" name="Januar" data-month="Januar" href="#">Januar</a>` (without the onclick and URL) and your jQuery code should be: `$(".btn-outline-dark").click(function(oEvent) { oEvent.preventDefault();
  const sMonth = oEvent.currentTarget.attributes["data-month"].value;
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "index.php",
      data: {
          name: "Januar"
      },
      success: function (response) { alert(response); },
      error: function (error) {}
  });
})`

Comment: You could also fetch the data attribute more nicely using jquery: instead of `oEvent.currentTarget.attributes["data-month"].value;` you can write simply `$(this).data("month");` (see https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: Mmm... via the `jQuery` route when `submitting`, the `PHP`-Code remains unexecuted, i.e. there is not an additional "Hallo Welt" (`echo "Hallo Welt";`) in the page, when `submitted` via the `buttons` it does. Why/how ?

Comment: Actually I just noticed another thing...your ajax code is sending a variable called "name" but your php code is testing for a variable called "januar". These are not the same, obviously. The _value_ of the "name" variable is "januar" but `isset()` tests for the existence of a variable with that name, not for the value inside it

Comment: I used it due to when adding the `name` property to buttons the `isset` executes. I tried all the routes for jQuery, the PHP simply doesn't execute in the now display of page.

Comment: You must adjust the isset before you get any results, for a start. E.g. `if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
`

Comment: If you still don't have any luck after that then 1) [edit] your question to show your latest code, and 2) use your browser's Developer Tools to debug the JS and see what happens to the ajax request